# How to set multiple setTimeouts start at the same time but with different time delays on Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I was just a little curious about using `setTimeout` inside an `async function`
so I tried to do something like this:

```
const { setTimeout } = require('timers/promises');

async function secondsToWait(sec) {
    await setTimeout(sec * 1000);
}

async function printSomething() {
    console.log(1);
    await secondsToWait(1);
    console.log(2);
    await secondsToWait(2);
    console.log(3);
    await secondsToWait(3);
    console.log(4);
}
```

Now, what I'm expecting is to print `1` immediately, then print `2` after
a second, then print `3` after a second, then print `4` after a second...

The thing is after it prints `2` after a second has passed, it prints `3` after
`2` seconds has passed, and prints `4` after `3` seconds has passed.

I was expecting it to behave like the typical `setTimeout` function
outside Node.js where after the functions
`secondsToWait(1), secondsToWait(2), secondsToWait(3)` are invoked
their timers start at the same time but finishes differently based
on their time delays.

```
setTimeout(() => { print something }, 1000);
setTimeout(() => { print something }, 2000);
setTimeout(() => { print something }, 3000);
```

So how can I do something like this in Node.js without using the
traditional `setTimeout` function of `JavaScript`? Preferrably using it
within an `async function`?

I've tried to modify the asynchronous `secondsToWait()` function to this:

```
await function secondsToWait(sec) {
    sec = 1;
    await setTimeout(sec * 1000);
}
```

I've just permanently set the time delay seconds to `1`, so no matter what
the time that will be passed into the function it will always have a
`1` second time delay. Well obviously, I just fooled myself doing this...

So how can I do this using the `setTimeout` from `'timers/promises'` module?
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't do what you expect because your expectation is wrong.

`await` will literally *wait*. So it prints 1, then waits 1 seconds, prints 2, then waits **2** seconds, etc.

What you're describing is something like:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(1), 1000);
setTimeout(() => console.log(2), 2000);
setTimeout(() => console.log(3), 3000);
setTimeout(() => console.log(4), 4000);
```

Where all the timeouts get queued all at once.

If you want it to wait 1 second in between prints then do:

```
async function printSomething() {
    console.log(1);
    await secondsToWait(1);
    console.log(2);
    await secondsToWait(1); // always 1
    console.log(3);
    await secondsToWait(1); // again, just 1
    console.log(4);
}
```

Comment: I was just wondering if such a thing is possible... Thanks for answering...